# Oracle SQL MERGE INTO giving ORA-00918 ambiguously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I'm migrating from SQL Server to Oracle and I'm having problems with a few queries that are simple updates with inner joins. I've compared my scenario with any example I can find here and elsewhere and I'm just not seeing where the problem lies.

Below is SQL Server version:

```
UPDATE Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth
SET Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Business_L1 = List_BusOrg.Business_L1, 
    Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Business_L2 = List_BusOrg.Business_L2, 
    Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Business_L3 = List_BusOrg.Business_L3, 
    Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Business_L4 = List_BusOrg.Business_L3, 
    Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Business_Segment = List_BusOrg.Business_Segment
FROM PSME.CapCostFore.Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth 
INNER JOIN PSME.Glob.List_BusOrg 
ON LTRIM(RTRIM(Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth.Bus_Code)) = List_BusOrg.Bus_Code
```

Oracle attempt:

```
   MERGE INTO CAPREPACCTWALKCURMNTH CAP1
   USING (SELECT CAP2.ROWID, BUS.Business_L1, BUS.Business_L2, BUS.Business_L3, 
      BUS.Business_L3, BUS.Business_Segment
   FROM CAPREPACCTWALKCURMNTH CAP2
          JOIN GLOBLISTBUSORG BUS   
          ON (CAP2.Bus_Code = BUS.Bus_Code )
   ) src
   ON ( CAP1.ROWID = src.ROWID )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CAP1.Business_L1 = src.Business_L1,
                                CAP1.Business_L2 = src.Business_L2,
                                CAP1.Business_L3 = src.Business_L3,
                                CAP1.Business_L4 = src.Business_L3,
                                CAP1.Business_Segment = src.Business_Segment;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're converting an `UPDATE` to a `MERGE`.  A correlated `UPDATE` in Oracle would look like this

```
UPDATE Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth currMnth
SET (Business_L1, Business_L2, Business_L3,
     Business_L4, Business_Segment ) = 
        (SELECT Business_L1, 
                Business_L2,
                Business_L3,
                Business_L4,
                Business_Segment 
           FROM PSME.Glob.List_BusOrg busOrg
          WHERE trim( currMnth.bus_code ) = busOrg.busCode)
```

if your intention is to update every row in the `Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth` table or

```
UPDATE Rep_AcctWalk_CurrentMnth currMnth
SET (Business_L1, Business_L2, Business_L3,
     Business_L4, Business_Segment ) = 
        (SELECT Business_L1, 
                Business_L2,
                Business_L3,
                Business_L4,
                Business_Segment 
           FROM PSME.Glob.List_BusOrg busOrg
          WHERE trim( currMnth.bus_code ) = busOrg.busCode)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM PSME.Glob.List_BusOrg busOrg
                WHERE trim( currMnth.bus_code ) = busOrg.busCode )
```

if you only want to update rows where there is a match.

If you want to use a `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO CAPREPACCTWALKCURMNTH CAP
   USING (SELECT BUS.Business_L1, 
                 BUS.Business_L2, 
                 BUS.Business_L3, 
                 BUS.Business_L4, 
                 BUS.Business_Segment
            FROM GLOBLISTBUSORG BUS   
   ) src
   ON ( CAP.Bus_Code = src.Bus_Code )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CAP.Business_L1 = src.Business_L1,
                                CAP.Business_L2 = src.Business_L2,
                                CAP.Business_L3 = src.Business_L3,
                                CAP.Business_L4 = src.Business_L4,
                                CAP.Business_Segment = src.Business_Segment;
```

Comment: Excellent! I was using MERGE because that's what the migration tool said was the translation and some Googling kept telling me you couldn't have joins in updates requiring the use of MERGE. Thank you very much for giving me a good example of both.

Oh, and I realized why it was giving me the ambiguous error. The migration utility had it selecting BUS.Business_L3 twice without giving the second one a different alias. Hah! Guess I should have looked at it for another day.. lol.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Justin's comments - which are all alternative ways to write this - The problem is the rowid value on the inner query, it needs to be alias'ed to then be used in the merge ON statement - its an annoying little quirk, but one that you would want to know about.

```
MERGE INTO CAPREPACCTWALKCURMNTH CAP1
   USING (SELECT CAP2.ROWID as row_id, BUS.Business_L1, BUS.Business_L2, BUS.Business_L3, 
      BUS.Business_L3, BUS.Business_Segment
   FROM CAPREPACCTWALKCURMNTH CAP2
          JOIN GLOBLISTBUSORG BUS   
          ON (CAP2.Bus_Code = BUS.Bus_Code )
   ) src
   ON ( CAP1.ROWID = src.row_id )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CAP1.Business_L1 = src.Business_L1,
                                CAP1.Business_L2 = src.Business_L2,
                                CAP1.Business_L3 = src.Business_L3,
                                CAP1.Business_L4 = src.Business_L3,
                                CAP1.Business_Segment = src.Business_Segment;
```